# LINQ - XML select node generic

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

I m trying to strip my XML and keep only nodes which I need

Input XML is

```
 <Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Name>Sam</Name>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
    <Address2>
      <Country>UK</Country>
      <Zip>E157JQ</Zip>
    </Address2>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Name>Lucy</Name>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Country>USA</Country>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
    <Address2>
      <Country>UK</Country>
      <Zip>E184JQ</Zip>
    </Address2>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

My code is as below.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream s = openFileDialog1.OpenFile();
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(s);
        string keep = "EmpId,Sex,Address,Zip,Address2,Country"; \\ I can change this format
        string desStr = "Employee";
            string[] strArr = keep.Split(',');

            var nodesToDelete = xDoc.Root.Descendants(desStr)
                .SelectMany(el => el.Descendants()
                                  .Where(a => !strArr.Contains(a.Name.ToString())));

            foreach (var node in nodesToDelete.ToList())
                node.Remove();

            richTextBox1.Text = xDoc.ToString();
    }
```

Output i get from above is

```
<Employees>
      <Employee>
        <EmpId>1</EmpId>
        <Sex>Male</Sex>
        <Address>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Zip>95220</Zip>
        </Address>
        <Address2>
          <Country>UK</Country>
          <Zip>E157JQ</Zip>
        </Address2>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
        <EmpId>2</EmpId>
        <Sex>Female</Sex>
        <Address>
          <Country>USA</Country>
          <Zip>95220</Zip>
        </Address>
        <Address2>
          <Country>UK</Country>
          <Zip>E184JQ</Zip>
        </Address2>
      </Employee>
    </Employees>
```

Output I need is

```
<Employees>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>1</EmpId>
    <Sex>Male</Sex>
    <Address>
     <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
    <Address2>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Address2>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmpId>2</EmpId>
    <Sex>Female</Sex>
    <Address>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address>
    <Address2>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Address2>
  </Employee>
</Employees>
```

How can I query Address\Zip and Address2\Country I need this to be generic (hence string keep can be changed) so I cant hardcode the node names.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you want to make the XML look like there is always only *Zip* under *Address* node and only *Country* - under *Address2*?

Comment: I m trying to make it input driven so if the string keep = "EmpId,Sex,Address,Zip,Address2,Country"; \\ I can change this format so if Address\Zip then my XML should have <Address>
      <Zip>95220</Zip>
    </Address> if its Address2\Country then my XML should be <Address2>
      <Country>UK</Country>
    </Address2>

Comment: Do you need the input to remain in a string format? Because what you are trying to do requires a tree-like input definition, parsing such a string will be cumbersome.

Comment: Doesnt have to be in a string format. It will be passed as a string but I can convert it to any format/Objects.

Comment: The question is whether you receive the input through UI from the end user or from some configuration. In case of configuration, better use XSD of the final XML format; in case of a user input, you will have either to provide a convenient UI or invent another format allowing you to specify nodes' hierarchies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it depends on how much you want to this be generic.
This is a somewhat hackish way to keep your current code structure.

```
string keep = @"EmpId,Sex,Address,Address\Zip,Address2,Address2\Country";
string desStr = "Employee";
string[] strArr = keep.Split(',');

var nodesToDelete = xDoc.Root.Descendants(desStr)
                .SelectMany(el => el.Descendants()
                                  .Where(a => 
                                    {
                                        if (a.Parent.Name == desStr)
                                        {
                                            return !strArr.Contains(a.Name.ToString());
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            return !strArr.Contains(a.Parent.Name + @"\" + a.Name);
                                        }

                                    }));

foreach (var node in nodesToDelete.ToList())
      node.Remove();
```

Proper way would be to keep full paths to all the nodes you want to keep.

Answer (score 0):

My way:

```
string keep = "Employees,Employee,EmpId,Sex,Address2,Address,Address.Zip,Address2.Country"; // I can change this format
string[] strArr = keep.Split(',');

    foreach (var node in xDoc.Descendants().ToArray())
    {
        var path = Path(node);
        if (!strArr.Any(path.EndsWith))
        {
            node.Remove();
        }
    }

    var results = xDoc.ToString();
}

private static string Path(XElement x)
{
    if (x.Parent != null)
    {
        return Path(x.Parent) + "." + x.Name;
    }

    return x.Name.ToString();
}
```